# Python HTML and script not working after "import pytube"

Tags: python, pytube

So, Im trying to do a conversor, and I had a successful work at it, but, when I was trying to execute the python script by the localhost, it simply didn't work.(btw, Im using XAMPP as the local server)

Here is a code that functions until before the "import pytube":

```
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
import sys
import os
print("<html><head><title>HelloCGI</title></head")
print("<body><h1><i>Hello</h1></body></html>")
import pytube
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH4F1Tdb040"
yt = pytube.YouTube(url)
yt.streams.last().download(r'C:\xampp\htdocs\converter_My\songs')
os.chdir(r'C:\xampp\htdocs\converter_My\songs')
os.system('ren *.webm *.mp3')
```

Comment: Please add the error output to your question.

Comment: You might find youtube-dl useful. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=youtube-dl&atb=v110-5_b&ia=web

Comment: I've tried to use it, but It never worked..

Comment: You might find ffmpeg useful as well https://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Actually, there is no output error on my page.. that's why Im here..

Comment: Have you installed with 'pip install pytube' ?

Comment: When I execute the command in the VisualStudioCode ide, it goes really well

Comment: yes, I have installed

Comment: ok. XAMP is not python. Write up your code as a shell script and then use PHP to call that script.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for some stupid reason, I put the import pytube after the print's, and then, it went...
    #!C:\xampp\htdocs\converter_My\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
    print("Content-type: text/html\n")
    import sys
    import os

```
print("<html><head><title>HelloCGI</title></head")
print("<body><h1><i>Hello</h1></body></html>")

import pytube
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44Mz-kwonWk"
yt = pytube.YouTube(url)

yt.streams.last().download(r'C:\xampp\htdocs\converter_My\songs')


os.chdir(r'C:\xampp\htdocs\converter_My\songs')
os.system('ren *.webm *.mp3')
```

Maybe I made you waste a little bit of your time, but thank you...:)

Answer (score 1):

I always need to do it:

```
from pytube import*
import pytube
```

I hope it works :)

PS: You don't add error message so it is litle hard to repair
EDIT: Make sure then using pip you have console with ***ADMIN*** privilages

Comment: I know but I don't find other ways to do it

Comment: open pytube package folder, see what functions are importable and then import accordingly

Comment: Yeah, meybe works but now I am working on local server. My uncle have a lot of computers and server with client will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem but make sure while you are installing them use 
1.pip for python2 
2.pip3 for python3
so with python3 use

```
pip3 install PyTube
```

make sure to take care of t